# Image snipping from page

Tags: angular

I would like to build image snipping functionality with Angular 6+. My requirement is like -

1. On web page, user can select an area using mouse drag (in rectangle format).
2. capture the selected area and add as image in clipboard.
3. when user perform action such as "copy from clipboard",  last saved image to clipboard get retrieved.

thank you in advance for your input.

Comment: My only advice is that unfortunately you have to start doing it and come back when you will have some problems with it.

Comment: @Antoniossss, thank you for reply. i thought to give a try to find, if someone had already built angular lib for copy image to/from clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the solution though its not 100%, but can serve the purpose ;) . adding my solution, may be it can help someone or someone can suggest improvement.

Here is my solution -

Implemented the solution using 2 angular lib
a. html2canvas - to capture the screen shot of your screen or target html tag.
b. angular-cropperjs - crop the image (htl2cavas out will be input for cropping).
Also you have to add dependency cropperjs which is used by angular-cropperjs.

Solution code -

------------Template code for html2canvas -------------------

```
<div class="row">
    <div  #screen>
  // add you code ()
</div>
```

---------------- component code or.ts file code ---------------
  @ViewChild('screen') screen: ElementRef;

```
captureView() {
    html2canvas(this.screen.nativeElement).then(canvas => {
      this.imageUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    });
  }
```

### // capture image and assign value to variable, which can be input to angular-cropper component.

--------------Template code for angular-cropperjs -------------------------------

```
<angular-cropper #angularCropper [cropperOptions]="angularCropperConfig" [imageUrl]="imageUrl" *ngIf="imageUrl"></angular-cropper>
```

-----------Component code for angular-cropperjs -----------------------------

```
@ViewChild('angularCropper') public angularCropper: CropperComponent;
  angularCropperConfig = {
    aspectRatio : 16/9,
    dragMode : 'drag',
    background : false,
    movable: true,
    rotatable : false,
    scalable: true,
    zoomable: false,
    viewMode: 1,
    checkImageOrigin : true,
    checkCrossOrigin: true
  };


selectImage() { 
cropImageOutput = this.angularCropper.cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL().toString());
  }
```

// this out will will be used where you want to paste cropped image

------------------- final code where you want to use it -----------------------

template code ---

```
<div>
              <canvas style="border:1px solid grey;" id="mycanvas"></canvas>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xl-1 col-md-1 col-xs-12 pull-left">
                <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="addImage()">add image</button>
              </div>
```

component code -

```
addImage(cropImageOutput ) {
const imageBlob = convertBase64ToBlob(cropImageOutput );
 if (imageBlob) {
              const canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
              const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

              // Create an image to render the blob on the canvas
              const img = new Image();

              // Once the image loads, render the img on the canvas
              img.onload = function () {
                // Update dimensions of the canvas with the dimensions of the image
                canvas.width = this.width;
                canvas.height = this.height;

                // Draw the image
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
              };

              // Crossbrowser support for URL
              const URLObj = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

              // Creates a DOMString containing a URL representing the object given in the parameter
              // namely the original Blob
              img.src = URLObj.createObjectURL(imageBlob);
            }
  }

/**
 * CONVERT BASE64 TO BLOB
 * @param Base64Image Pass base64 image data to convert into the blob
 */
function convertBase64ToBlob(base64Image: string) {
  // SPLIT INTO TWO PARTS
  const parts = base64Image.split(';base64,');
  // HOLD THE CONTENT TYPE
  const imageType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
  // DECODE BASE64 STRING
  const decodedData = window.atob(parts[1]);
  // CREATE UNIT8ARRAY OF SIZE SAME AS ROW DATA LENGTH
  const uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(decodedData.length);
  // INSERT ALL CHARACTER CODE INTO UINT8ARRAY
  for (let i = 0; i < decodedData.length; ++i) {
    uInt8Array[i] = decodedData.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  // RETURN BLOB IMAGE AFTER CONVERSION
  return new Blob([uInt8Array], { type: imageType });
}
```